# Positioning of DIV's using CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have tried to solve this issue for too long time and thus now it's time to ask for help.

I have this fiddle which show what I want to do: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erikhogs/y7uknqs9/1/)

This is my HTML:

```
    <div id="pagecontent">
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="content">
            <img src="http://www.blogcdn.com/www.engadget.com/media/2012/09/09-20-2012form-1-on-desk00-1348689824.jpg" width="100px">
        </div>
        <div id="link">
            <div class="linkbox">
                <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-uinvert-dock/256/Chart_-_Google_Docs.png" width="20px">
               <div class="linkcontent">
                   <img src="http://www.blogcdn.com/www.engadget.com/media/2012/09/09-20-2012form-1-on-desk00-1348689824.jpg" width="100%">
               </div>
               <div class="linkcontentzoom">
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   <div id="footer">
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 1001px) {
  #pagecontent {
    margin-left:3%;
    margin-right:3%;
    margin-top:2%;
    margin-bottom:2%;
  }
  #header {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
  }
  #footer {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  #pagecontent {
    margin-left:2%;
    margin-right:2%;
    margin-top:2%;
    margin-bottom:2%;
  }
  #header {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
  }
  #footer {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #pagecontent {
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-right:15px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
  }
  #header {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
  }
  #footer {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  #pagecontent {
    margin-left:0%;
    margin-right:0%;
    margin-top:0%;
    margin-bottom:0%;
  }
  #header {
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
  }
  #footer {
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
  }
}

#header {
    background-color:green;
}
#main {
    height:100px;
    min-height:100%;
}
#content {
    float: right;
    min-height: 100%; 
    height: auto !important; /*Cause footer to stick to bottom in IE 6*/
    height: 100%; 
    background-color:grey;
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    //width:100%;
    //min-height:100px;
}
#link {
    width: 30px;
    min-height: 100%; 
    height: auto !important; /*Cause footer to stick to bottom in IE 6*/
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    /* Set our transitions up. */
    -webkit-transition: width 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: width 0.8s;
    transition: width 0.8s;
}
.linkbox {
    width:100%;
    /* Set our transitions up. */
    -webkit-transition: width 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: width 0.8s;
    transition: width 0.8s;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-top:5px;
    float:left;
}
.linkcontent {
    width:0%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.linkcontentzoom {
    display:none;
}
#footer {
    background-color:green;
    clear:both;
}
```

Jquery:

```
var linkstatus=false;
$('body').on('click', '#link', function() {
    if(!linkstatus) {
        $(this).css('width', '250px');
        $('.linkcontent').css('width', '100%');
        linkstatus=true;
    }
    else {
        $(this).css('width', '30px');
        $('.linkcontent').css('width', '0%');
        linkstatus=false;
    }
});
```

So this is my problem(s):

1. The div "footer" should be placed at the bottom, even if the content does not cover the entire page and if content is more you shouldn't be able to see the "footer" until you scroll to it, i.e. I can't use position:absolute bottom:0px;
2. the div "main" should fill the space between the "header" and "footer" (and the div's in "main" ("link" and "content" should have the same height, i.e. 100%). I've seen similar questions here on SO but nothing have solved my problem.
3. When clicking on "link" it grows to 250px. this also reveals more content (an image in this case). However, for some reason everything in the "link" div gets placed between link and footer.

As I said, I've been stuck here for a while so help with any of the issues would be much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for your reply (how fast aren't you)!!! The footer is positioned below everything, however I want it to bee in the bottom even if there's no content at all.

Comment: Right, if there is no text you can fix it to the bottom like so: http://jsfiddle.net/y7uknqs9/5/

Comment: However then if you add more content that wont be pushed "under" the screen

Comment: Do you have your problem solved?

Comment: @SimplyCraig: Thanks for your reply, however as you say, this doesn't "push" it down of more content is added.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my question and for the sake of maybe helping others in the future, I'm posting my answer here!

I found some good tips in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322610/100-height-div-between-header-and-footer) questions.

My code now looks like this (started from scratch)...

HTML

```
<div id="header"></div>

    <div id="link">
        <div class="linkbox">
            <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-uinvert-dock/256/Chart_-_Google_Docs.png" width="20px">

                <div class="linkcontent">
                    <img src="http://www.blogcdn.com/www.engadget.com/media/2012/09/09-20-2012form-1-on-desk00-1348689824.jpg" width="100%">
                </div>

               <div class="linkcontentzoom">
               </div>
        </div>

        <div class="linkbox">
            <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-uinvert-dock/256/Chart_-_Google_Docs.png" width="20px">

                <div class="linkcontent">
                    <img src="http://www.blogcdn.com/www.engadget.com/media/2012/09/09-20-2012form-1-on-desk00-1348689824.jpg" width="100%">
                </div>

               <div class="linkcontentzoom">
               </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content">

    </div>

<div id="pushdiv"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin:10;
}
#header {
    height:50px;
    background-color:green;
}
#content {
    background-color:blue;
    padding-left:50px;
    width: calc(100% - 50px);
    margin:0 auto -50px;
    min-height:calc(100% - 50px);
}
#link {
    width:50px;
    background-color:grey;
    float:left;
    margin:0 auto -50px;
    min-height:calc(100% - 50px);
    overflow:hidden;
    /* Set our transitions up. */
    -webkit-transition: width 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: width 0.8s;
    transition: width 0.8s;
    margin-bottom:-50px;
}
.linkbox{
    margin:5px;
}
.linkbox:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom:50px;
}
.linkcontent {
    /* Set our transitions up. */
    -webkit-transition: width 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: width 0.8s;
    transition: width 0.8s;
    display:none;
}
#pushdiv {
    clear:both;
}
#footer {
    height:50px;
    background-color:green;
    clear:both;
}
```

and finally Jquery

```
var linkstatus=false;
$('body').on('click', '#link', function() {
    if(!linkstatus) {
        $(this).css('width', '250px');
        $('.linkcontent').css('width', '100%');
        $('.linkcontent').css('display', 'inline');
        linkstatus=true;
    }
    else {
        $(this).css('width', '50px');
        $('.linkcontent').css('width', '0px');
        $('.linkcontent').css('display', 'none');
        linkstatus=false;
    }
});
```